# CosmosDatabase.createContainerIfNotExists() -> "Resource with specified id, name, or unique index already exists."

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

If I call the the method: `CosmosDatabase.createContainerIfNotExists(x)` I receive the error message: `Resource with specified id, name, or unique index already exists.`

How I have to interpret this error?

The full exception stacktrace:

```
{"ClassName":"CosmosException","userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.13.0 Linux/4.15.0-124-generic JRE/11.0.11","statusCode":409,"resourceAddress":"https://10.10.10.16:8081/dbs/jenkins21/colls","error":"{\"code\":\"Conflict\",\"message\":\"Message: {\\\"Errors\\\":[\\\"Resource with specified id, name, or unique index already exists.\\\"]}\\r\\nActivityId: f42970e5-c07b-45f9-896e-62a0aa00122a, Request URI: /apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbMaster0/partitions/780e44f4-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/, RequestStats: \\r\\nRequestStartTime: 2021-07-20T02:05:58.8219453Z, RequestEndTime: 2021-07-20T02:05:58.8239187Z,  Number of regions attempted:1\\r\\nResponseTime: 2021-07-20T02:05:58.8239187Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://10.10.10.16:10251/apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbMaster0/partitions/780e44f4-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/, LSN: 32164, GlobalCommittedLsn: -1, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: True, StatusCode: 409, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 0, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#32164, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Collection, OperationType: BatchApply\\r\\n, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0, StatusCode: Conflict\",\"additionalErrorInfo\":null}","innerErrorMessage":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Resource with specified id, name, or unique index already exists.\"]}\r\nActivityId: f42970e5-c07b-45f9-896e-62a0aa00122a, Request URI: /apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbMaster0/partitions/780e44f4-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/, RequestStats: \r\nRequestStartTime: 2021-07-20T02:05:58.8219453Z, RequestEndTime: 2021-07-20T02:05:58.8239187Z,  Number of regions attempted:1\r\nResponseTime: 2021-07-20T02:05:58.8239187Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://10.10.10.16:10251/apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbMaster0/partitions/780e44f4-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/, LSN: 32164, GlobalCommittedLsn: -1, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: True, StatusCode: 409, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 0, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#32164, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Collection, OperationType: BatchApply\r\n, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0, StatusCode: Conflict","causeInfo":null,"responseHeaders":"{Transfer-Encoding=chunked, x-ms-last-state-change-utc=Wed, 14 Jul 2021 20:52:01.947 GMT, x-ms-current-replica-set-size=1, Server=Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0, x-ms-request-duration-ms=1.132, x-ms-session-token=0:-1#32164, Access-Control-Allow-Origin=, lsn=32164, x-ms-schemaversion=1.11, x-ms-transport-request-id=41722, x-ms-number-of-read-regions=0, x-ms-current-write-quorum=1, x-ms-cosmos-quorum-acked-llsn=32164, x-ms-quorum-acked-lsn=32164, Date=Tue, 20 Jul 2021 02:05:58 GMT, x-ms-activity-id=f42970e5-c07b-45f9-896e-62a0aa00122a, x-ms-xp-role=0, x-ms-global-Committed-lsn=-1, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true, x-ms-cosmos-llsn=32164, x-ms-gatewayversion=version=2.11.0, x-ms-serviceversion=version=2.11.0.0, Content-Type=application/json}","requestHeaders":"[Accept=application/json, x-ms-date=Tue, 20 Jul 2021 02:05:58 GMT, Content-Type=application/json]","cosmosDiagnostics":{"userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.13.0 Linux/4.15.0-124-generic JRE/11.0.11","requestLatencyInMs":368,"requestStartTimeUTC":"2021-07-20T02:05:58.681410Z","requestEndTimeUTC":"2021-07-20T02:05:59.050232Z","connectionMode":"GATEWAY","responseStatisticsList":[],"supplementalResponseStatisticsList":[],"addressResolutionStatistics":{},"regionsContacted":["https://10.10.10.16:8081/"],"retryContext":{"retryCount":0,"statusAndSubStatusCodes":null,"retryLatency":0},"metadataDiagnosticsContext":{"metadataDiagnosticList":null},"serializationDiagnosticsContext":{"serializationDiagnosticsList":[{"serializationType":"CONTAINER_SERIALIZATION","startTimeUTC":"2021-07-20T02:05:58.681516Z","endTimeUTC":"2021-07-20T02:05:58.681552Z","durationInMicroSec":36}]},"gatewayStatistics":{"sessionToken":null,"operationType":"Create","statusCode":409,"subStatusCode":0,"requestCharge":null,"requestTimeline":[{"eventName":"connectionCreated","startTimeUTC":"2021-07-20T02:05:58.681681Z","durationInMicroSec":117},{"eventName":"connectionConfigured","startTimeUTC":"2021-07-20T02:05:58.681798Z","durationInMicroSec":22},{"eventName":"requestSent","startTimeUTC":"2021-07-20T02:05:58.681820Z","durationInMicroSec":170},{"eventName":"transitTime","startTimeUTC":"2021-07-20T02:05:58.681990Z","durationInMicroSec":367906},{"eventName":"received","startTimeUTC":"2021-07-20T02:05:59.049896Z","durationInMicroSec":150}]},"systemInformation":{"usedMemory":"71893 KB","availableMemory":"452395 KB","systemCpuLoad":"(2021-07-20T02:05:31.477916Z 48.1%), (2021-07-20T02:05:36.477915Z 34.6%), (2021-07-20T02:05:41.477923Z 37.8%), (2021-07-20T02:05:46.477917Z 42.1%), (2021-07-20T02:05:51.477942Z 61.4%), (2021-07-20T02:05:56.477908Z 57.0%)"},"clientCfgs":{"id":0,"numberOfClients":1,"connCfg":{"rntbd":"(cto:PT5S, rto:PT5S, icto:PT0S, ieto:PT1H, mcpe:130, mrpc:30, cer:false)","gw":"(cps:1000, rto:PT5S, icto:null, p:false)","other":"(ed: true, cs: false)"},"consistencyCfg":"(consistency: null, mm: true, prgns: [])"}}}
    at com.azure.cosmos.BridgeInternal.createCosmosException(BridgeInternal.java:463)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.validateOrThrow(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:365)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.lambda$toDocumentServiceResponse$0(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:294)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:118)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:220)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onNext(FluxDoFinally.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:184)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:128)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:259)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:389)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:396)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:452)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:684)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:94)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1533)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1294)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1331)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:508)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:447)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$1.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:388)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
```

Comment: Do you have a container with the same name? Can you share the definition of that container as well as the container you're trying to create? Ideally this error should not happen.

Comment: This code sequence works with thousand of unit tests with the same container definition. This should not be the relevant. Debug code in a catch block show with readAllContainers() that this container exists if the error occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work around the problem with a try catch block and repeat the operation if this error occur. Debug code show that the container exists after the exception occur.

Our application is multi threading with lazy initialization. Can be that 2 threads try to create the needed container at the same time. The error is difficult to reproduce.

Its sounds this method is not atomic on the database like the method name suggested and also does not handle it in the driver. The very bad API documentation does not says any over thread behavior. With such API documentation it is not possible to write stable software. It required a try and error.